# Reaching a conclusion before formulating an argument

Tags: word-choice

What is a good word for saying that a person has reached a conclusion before properly formulating an argument?

For example, a logical train of thought would be 'My current computer is slow, this is decreasing my productivity, so therefore I would solve this by buying a new computer', whereas a person using this type of reasoning would say 'I want a new computer, let's think up reasons why this would be good. I know, I think I'm not working as well as I possibly could be.'

Comment: "behaving typically"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be said to be *rationalizing* your behavior or your decision.

One definition of [rationalize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rationalize) is:

> To devise self-satisfying but incorrect reasons for one's behavior.

Comment: I had originally provided *jumping to conclusions* which fits the title, but does not fit the explanation given in the question body.  *Rationalize* definitely is the right word for what's being described.

Answer (score 0):

This is one definition of a *[foregone conclusion](http://www.wordnik.com/words/foregone%20conclusion)*:

> a conclusion which has preceded argument or examination; a predetermined conclusion.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: This certainly isn't the way I use the phrase, but equally certainly that's no reason to downvote.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm also more familiar with the _inevitable outcome_ use of the phrase, but thought this alternate use fit the question quite well.